# Can I use AutoHotKey to bind CapsLock+n to down arrow?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Can I use AutoHotKey to bind CapsLock+n to down arrow? If so, how do I do it?

I have managed to bind just caps lock to down arrow without problems, but I want to bind the combination of caps lock and the n-key to down arrow, so that I can bind various combinations of caps lock and some key to some action. I cannot simply rebind caps lock to alt/shift/ctrl and then bind for example ctrl+n, since that would create conflicts with other existing short cut commands.

Thanks /Erik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
CapsLock & n::send {down}
```